# How to get the URL that opened my app (using Branch)?

Tags: ios, branch, deep-linking

I have set a universal link that's correctly opening my app when I tap on it, however I tried it when the app is not in background. The app gets opened through `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but I don't see the URL anywhere in the options dictionary. So what should I do ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I asked that question too quickly, I finally fetched it in AppDelegate in:

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool`

Contained in `userActivity.webpageURL`.